# How can I read strings from a .txt file in Java?

Tags: java, exception, bufferedreader, filereader

My code always generates an exception, if I start it.

```
package wrs;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Random;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;


public class mainWRS{
static ArrayList<String> al1 = new ArrayList<String>();

static JFrame frame1 = new JFrame("Game");
static JPanel panel1 = new JPanel();
static JLabel label1 = new JLabel();

static JButton buttona = new JButton("a");
static JButton buttonb = new JButton("b");
static JButton buttonc = new JButton("c");
static JButton buttond = new JButton("d");
static JButton buttone = new JButton("e");
static JButton buttonf = new JButton("f");
static JButton buttong = new JButton("g");
static JButton buttonh = new JButton("h");
static JButton buttoni = new JButton("i");
static JButton buttonj = new JButton("j");
static JButton buttonk = new JButton("k");
static JButton buttonl = new JButton("l");
static JButton buttonm = new JButton("m");
static JButton buttonn = new JButton("n");
static JButton buttono = new JButton("o");
static JButton buttonp = new JButton("p");
static JButton buttonq = new JButton("q");
static JButton buttonr = new JButton("r");
static JButton buttons = new JButton("s");
static JButton buttont = new JButton("t");
static JButton buttonu = new JButton("u");
static JButton buttonv = new JButton("v");
static JButton buttonw = new JButton("w");
static JButton buttonx = new JButton("x");
static JButton buttony = new JButton("y");
static JButton buttonz = new JButton("z");

static Random rand = new Random();

static boolean end = false;

static String Word = "";

static mainWRS helper = new mainWRS();

static ArrayList<Integer> lp = new ArrayList<Integer>();

static ArrayList<String> used = new ArrayList<String>();

static char[] cw,cdisp;

static File file = new File("C:\Users\Jan\Desktop\eTest.txt");
static FileReader fr = new FileReader(file);
static BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);

public static void main(String[]args){                    // <-- line 70
    setup();
}

private static void setup() {
    frame1.setSize(500, 500);
    frame1.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.decode("#00FF00"));
    frame1.setLocation(0, 0);
    frame1.setVisible(true);
    frame1.setResizable(false);

    panel1.setLayout(null);
    panel1.setBackground(Color.decode("#00FF00"));

    label1.setSize(480, 50);
    label1.setLocation(10, 175);
    label1.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
    label1.setFont(label1.getFont().deriveFont(18f));

    int bpx = 5;
    int bpy = 220;

    buttona.setSize(50,50);
    buttona.setLocation(bpx, bpy);
    bpx += 55;
    buttonb.setSize(50,50);
    buttonb.setLocation(bpx, bpy);
    bpx += 55;
    buttonc.setSize(50,50);
    buttonc.setLocation(bpx, bpy);
    bpx += 55;
    buttond.setSize(50,50);
    buttond.setLocation(bpx, bpy);
    bpx += 55;
    buttone.setSize(50,50);
    buttone.setLocation(bpx, bpy);
    bpx += 55;
    buttonf.setSize(50,50);
    buttonf.setLocation(bpx, bpy);
    bpx += 55;
    buttong.setSize(50,50);
    buttong.setLocation(bpx, bpy);
    bpx += 55;
    buttonh.setSize(50,50);
    buttonh.setLocation(bpx, bpy);
    bpx += 55;
    buttoni.setSize(50,50);
    buttoni.setLocation(bpx, bpy);
    bpy += 55;
    bpx = 5;
    buttonj.setSize(50,50);
    buttonj.setLocation(bpx, bpy);
    bpx += 55;
    buttonk.setSize(50,50);
    buttonk.setLocation(bpx, bpy);
    bpx += 55;
    buttonl.setSize(50,50);
    buttonl.setLocation(bpx, bpy);
    bpx += 55;
    buttonm.setSize(50,50);
    buttonm.setLocation(bpx, bpy);
    bpx += 55;
    buttonn.setSize(50,50);
    buttonn.setLocation(bpx, bpy);
    bpx += 55;
    buttono.setSize(50,50);
    buttono.setLocation(bpx, bpy);
    bpx += 55;
    buttonp.setSize(50,50);
    buttonp.setLocation(bpx, bpy);
    bpx += 55;
    buttonq.setSize(50,50);
    buttonq.setLocation(bpx, bpy);
    bpx += 55;
    buttonr.setSize(50,50);
    buttonr.setLocation(bpx, bpy);
    bpy += 55;
    bpx = 30;
    buttons.setSize(50,50);
    buttons.setLocation(bpx, bpy);
    bpx += 55;
    buttont.setSize(50,50);
    buttont.setLocation(bpx, bpy);
    bpx += 55;
    buttonu.setSize(50,50);
    buttonu.setLocation(bpx, bpy);
    bpx += 55;
    buttonv.setSize(50,50);
    buttonv.setLocation(bpx, bpy);
    bpx += 55;
    buttonw.setSize(50,50);
    buttonw.setLocation(bpx, bpy);
    bpx += 55;
    buttonx.setSize(50,50);
    buttonx.setLocation(bpx, bpy);
    bpx += 55;
    buttony.setSize(50,50);
    buttony.setLocation(bpx, bpy);
    bpx += 55;
    buttonz.setSize(50,50);
    buttonz.setLocation(bpx, bpy);
    bpx += 55;

    ActionListener actionListenera = new ActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            check("a");
        }
    };
    buttona.addActionListener(actionListenera);

    ActionListener actionListenerb = new ActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            check("b");
        }
    };
    buttonb.addActionListener(actionListenerb);

    ActionListener actionListenerc = new ActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            check("c");
        }
    };
    buttonc.addActionListener(actionListenerc);

    ActionListener actionListenerd = new ActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            check("d");
        }
    };
    buttond.addActionListener(actionListenerd);

    ActionListener actionListenere= new ActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            check("e");
        }
    };
    buttone.addActionListener(actionListenere);

    ActionListener actionListenerf= new ActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            check("f");
        }
    };
    buttonf.addActionListener(actionListenerf);

    ActionListener actionListenerg= new ActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            check("g");
        }
    };
    buttong.addActionListener(actionListenerg);

    ActionListener actionListenerh= new ActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            check("h");
        }
    };
    buttonh.addActionListener(actionListenerh);

    ActionListener actionListeneri= new ActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            check("i");
        }
    };
    buttoni.addActionListener(actionListeneri);

    ActionListener actionListenerj= new ActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            check("j");
        }
    };
    buttonj.addActionListener(actionListenerj);

    ActionListener actionListenerk= new ActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            check("k");
        }
    };
    buttonk.addActionListener(actionListenerk);

    ActionListener actionListenerl= new ActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            check("l");
        }
    };
    buttonl.addActionListener(actionListenerl);

    ActionListener actionListenerm= new ActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            check("m");
        }
    };
    buttonm.addActionListener(actionListenerm);

    ActionListener actionListenern= new ActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            check("n");
        }
    };
    buttonn.addActionListener(actionListenern);

    ActionListener actionListenero= new ActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            check("o");
        }
    };
    buttono.addActionListener(actionListenero);

    ActionListener actionListenerp= new ActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            check("p");
        }
    };
    buttonp.addActionListener(actionListenerp);

    ActionListener actionListenerq= new ActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            check("q");
        }
    };
    buttonq.addActionListener(actionListenerq);

    ActionListener actionListenerr= new ActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            check("r");
        }
    };
    buttonr.addActionListener(actionListenerr);

    ActionListener actionListeners= new ActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            check("s");
        }
    };
    buttons.addActionListener(actionListeners);

    ActionListener actionListenert= new ActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            check("t");
        }
    };
    buttont.addActionListener(actionListenert);

    ActionListener actionListeneru= new ActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            check("u");
        }
    };
    buttonu.addActionListener(actionListeneru);

    ActionListener actionListenerv= new ActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            check("v");
        }
    };
    buttonv.addActionListener(actionListenerv);

    ActionListener actionListenerw= new ActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            check("w");
        }
    };
    buttonw.addActionListener(actionListenerw);

    ActionListener actionListenerx= new ActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            check("x");
        }
    };
    buttonx.addActionListener(actionListenerx);

    ActionListener actionListenery= new ActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            check("y");
        }
    };
    buttony.addActionListener(actionListenery);

    ActionListener actionListenerz= new ActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            check("z");
        }
    };
    buttonz.addActionListener(actionListenerz);



    panel1.add(buttona);
    panel1.add(buttonb);
    panel1.add(buttonc);
    panel1.add(buttond);
    panel1.add(buttone);
    panel1.add(buttonf);
    panel1.add(buttong);
    panel1.add(buttonh);
    panel1.add(buttoni);
    panel1.add(buttonj);
    panel1.add(buttonk);
    panel1.add(buttonl);
    panel1.add(buttonm);
    panel1.add(buttonn);
    panel1.add(buttono);
    panel1.add(buttonp);
    panel1.add(buttonq);
    panel1.add(buttonr);
    panel1.add(buttons);
    panel1.add(buttont);
    panel1.add(buttonu);
    panel1.add(buttonv);
    panel1.add(buttonw);
    panel1.add(buttonx);
    panel1.add(buttony);
    panel1.add(buttonz);

    panel1.add(label1);
    frame1.add(panel1);

    aLFill();
    nWord();
}


private static void nWord() {
    int max = al1.size()-1;
    int min = 0;
    int randomNum = rand.nextInt((max - min) + 1) + min;
    String disp = "";
    label1.setText(al1.get(randomNum));
    for (int i = 0; i < al1.get(randomNum).length(); i++) {
        disp += ".";
    }
    game(al1.get(randomNum), disp);
}

private static void game(String Word1, String disp) {
    Word = Word1;
    cw = Word.toLowerCase().toCharArray();
    cdisp = disp.toCharArray();
    display(disp);
}

private static void check(String letter) {
    String disp = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < Word.length(); i++) {
        disp += ".";
    }
    used.add(letter);
    for (int i = 0; i < used.size(); i++) {
        if (Word.toLowerCase().contains(used.get(i))) {
            for (int j = 0; j < cw.length; j++) {
                if (cw[j] == letter.charAt(0)) {
                    lp.add(j);
                }
            }
            for (int j = 0; j < lp.size(); j++) {
                cdisp[lp.get(j)] = Word.charAt(lp.get(j));
            }
            disp = "";
            for (int j = 0; j < cdisp.length; j++) {
                disp += cdisp[j];
            }
        }
    }
    display(disp);
}

private static void display(String disp) {
    label1.setText(disp);
}

private static void aLFill() {

    String zeile1 = br.readLine();
    al1.add("Hallo");
    al1.add("Test");
    al1.add("Computersimulation");
    al1.add("Elefant");
}
}
```

It generates the error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
at wrs.mainWRS.main(mainWRS.java:70)
```

What have I done wrong?

//edited
Here only the piece of the code how generate the Error.

```
package sof;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;

public class wrs{
    static File file = new File("C:\\Users\\Jan\\Desktop\\Test.txt");
    static FileReader filereader = new FileReader(file);
    static BufferedReader bufferedreader = new BufferedReader(filereader);

public static void main(String[]args){                  //<-- Line 12
    }
}
```

The new Error is:

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem:

at sof.wrs.main(wrs.java:12)

Comment: And which line is the 70th ?

Comment: You should really format your code, and add camelCase formatting to variables!

Comment: Your code is far too long.  Cut it down, piece by piece, and when you have a small remainder that still shows the error, post it here.  In the process of cutting it down, you may find that the error disappears.  Look carefully at the bit you just cut out.  Concentrate on the piece of code that actually tries to open and read the file.

Comment: Your code didn't compile for me. There are several unhandled exceptions.

Comment: You have an unresolved compilation problem at mainWRS.java line 70. (I.E. a red squiggle you didn't fix. Eclipse will let you run code with red squiggles, and your program will crash when it gets to the squiggle. Normally you couldn't run code with red squiggles, but Eclipse tries to be "helpful")

Comment: Omg, I see **loads** of `static` keywords that could be removed if you were willing to create a instance of your class in the `main` method. That would also allow you to use more than 1 of those frames at the same time.

Comment: This way I also van use more than one JFrame

Comment: Your title has nothing to with your question. You're really expected to be able to resolve trivial compilation errors on your own. Or at least to be able to report them accurately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use one of these '/' instead of these '\' like this:

```
static File file = new File("C:/Users/Jan/Desktop/eTest.txt");
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use double '\' instead of one like this :

```
static File file = new File("C:\\Users\\Jan\\Desktop\\eTest.txt");
```

Comment: Thanks, but jet I've an other problem, the file couldn't be found although the file exist at this position.

Comment: if this is the correct path to the file , then it could be a permission problem , you have to start your code using an administrator account.

Comment: I've got the solution. I have to put '/' instead of this '\' like this:

static File file = new File("C:/Users/Jan/Desktop/eTest.txt");